# NetworkManager with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS : tethering through ethernet port needs manual off/on

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, tethering

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a Lenovo G70-80 laptop and am connected to my box through a Wifi link, which works fine.

I need to share this link to a device connected to my ethernet port (driven by the r8169 module). To achieve this, I set up the NetworkManager like this way for the ethernet link: IPV4 sharing, IPV6 sharing disabled, no security, automatic connexion, sharing allowed to all users.

When the laptop boots up, it gets the wifi connexion, sets up the Internet access very well. But it doesn't share my internet link to the ethernet port, so I have no tethering for my device.

I found this solution : I manually switch off the ethernet link in NetworkManager and switch it manually on one or two seconds after, and then the internet sharing trough ethernet works fine.

Why does my configuration not set up this tethering automatically ? Is there a misconfiguration anywhere? Is it a bug?

I tried the exactly same configuration of NetworkManager in Debian 11 (I have dual boot on my laptop), and the tethering trough ethernet is set up automatically at boot time. There is no further manual intervention necessary.

So I am lost and cannot explain that behaviour in Ubuntu.

---

Here are some contents:

```
damien@damien-Lenovo-G70-80:~$ sudo nmcli connection show
NAME                       UUID                                  TYPE       DEVICE 
Connexion filaire 1        cade8fd4-c674-3ef9-93ca-95334cabb4a8  ethernet   enp2s0 
Bbox-9CE598F5              f58ac981-c737-402a-860a-8348acfdea51  wifi       wlp3s0 
pan1                       72a3e182-b70f-4c8b-b687-0042f98741a4  bridge     pan1   
virbr0                     5366cdbc-d656-487d-87cd-9cb865750830  bridge     virbr0 
A22 de Mon compte Network  698a1d09-34fb-4f16-b416-531725befedf  bluetooth  --     
AndroidAP                  86627f14-6ac5-44d1-8683-6477a16872ac  wifi       --     
Félicien                   94953f1e-91ef-4d2e-9769-341b243d4a9a  wifi       --     
Mon compte's Galaxy A22    dfcae5a4-80d5-46cc-90ff-94377b86426c  wifi       --     
NUMERICABLE-938C           1595cd03-1329-48c6-b523-bda73bd1759c  wifi       --     
Réseau Galaxy J3 (2017)    1d82f1dc-5707-4748-a78c-0e10e282a843  bluetooth  --     
Réseau XCover 5 de Damien  37d936ff-0876-4bbc-bcf4-54cdab7ec7ac  bluetooth  --

damien@damien-Lenovo-G70-80:~$ sudo nmcli connection show 'Connexion filaire 1'
connection.id:                          Connexion filaire 1
connection.uuid:                        cade8fd4-c674-3ef9-93ca-95334cabb4a8
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-3-ethernet
connection.interface-name:              enp2s0
connection.autoconnect:                 oui
connection.autoconnect-priority:        -999
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.multi-connect:               0 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   1707052593
connection.read-only:                   non
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     inconnu
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
connection.dns-over-tls:                -1 (default)
connection.wait-device-timeout:         -1
802-3-ethernet.port:                    --
802-3-ethernet.speed:                   0
802-3-ethernet.duplex:                  --
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate:          non
802-3-ethernet.mac-address:             --
802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address:      --
802-3-ethernet.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-3-ethernet.mac-address-blacklist:   --
802-3-ethernet.mtu:                     auto
802-3-ethernet.s390-subchannels:        --
802-3-ethernet.s390-nettype:            --
802-3-ethernet.s390-options:            --
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:             default
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan-password:    --
802-3-ethernet.accept-all-mac-addresses:-1 (default)
ipv4.method:                            shared
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                non
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   non
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                oui
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     non
ipv4.may-fail:                          oui
ipv4.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-vendor-class-identifier:      --
ipv4.dhcp-reject-servers:               --
ipv6.method:                            disabled
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       --
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.routing-rules:                     --
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                non
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   non
ipv6.never-default:                     non
ipv6.may-fail:                          oui
ipv6.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.ra-timeout:                        0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                oui
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv6.token:                             --
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     non
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
GENERAL.NAME:                           Connexion filaire 1
GENERAL.UUID:                           cade8fd4-c674-3ef9-93ca-95334cabb4a8
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.STATE:                          activé
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        non
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       non
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    --
GENERAL.VPN:                            non
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/11
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.42.0.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.42.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

Yes, "connect automatically" is on, but I have to add that I also share at the same time my Wireless Internet connection through Bluetooth with the `blueman` application (local services).

This Bluetooth tethering gets up automatically and works fine, no manual intervention is necessary. There seems to be an interference between the two connection sharing, between Bluetooth and Ethernet.

Can the Bluetooth sharing be taking it all?

Comment: Are you sure that "connect automatically" is on? Have you tried running `nmcli connection show 'Name of your connection'` on each device and comparing the output?